# How to encode a numeric value as bytes

Tags: c

I need to be able to be able to send a numeric value to a remote socket server and so I need to encode possible numbers as bytes.

The numbers are up to 64 bit, ie requiring up to 8 bytes.  The very first byte is the type, and it is always a number under 255 so fits in 1 byte.

For example, if the number was 8 and the type was a 32 bit unsigned integer then the type would be 7 which would be copied to the first (leftmost) byte and then the next 4 bytes would be encoded with the actual number (8 in this case).

So in terms of bytes:

```
byte1: 7
byte2: 0
byte3: 0
byte4: 0
byte5: 8
```

I hope this is making sense.

Does this code to perform this encoding look like a reasonable approach?

```
int type = 7;
uint32_t number = 8;

unsigned char* msg7 = (unsigned char*)malloc(5);
unsigned char* p = msg7;

*p++ = type;

 for (int i = sizeof(uint32_t) - 1; i >= 0; --i) 
    *p++ = number & 0xFF << (i * 8);
```

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to explicitly cast `type` to avoid a warning:

```
*p++ = (unsigned char) type;
```

You want to encode the number with most significant byte first, but you're shifting in the wrong direction. The loop should be:

```
for (int i = sizeof(uint32_t) - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    *p++ = (unsigned char) ((number >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF);
```

It looks good otherwise.

Comment: You've also fixed another issue you haven't mentioned: his code was shifting the 0xff mask, not `number`, so 3 out of 4 of the bytes were always set to zero.  It's fixed in yours, though.

Comment: As in this case, whenever I'm not sure of precedence, I assume no one else will be sure either and I use parentheses to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean?

```
for (int i = sizeof(uint32_t) - 1; i >= 0; --i)
  *p++ = (number >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF;
```

Another option to might be to do

```
// this would work on Big endian systems, e.g. sparc
struct unsignedMsg {
    unsigned char type;
    uint32_t value;
}

unsignedMsg msg;
msg.type = 7;
msg.value = number;
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *) &msg;
```

or

```
unsigned char* p = 
p[0] = 7;
*((uint32_t *) &(p[1])) = number;
```

Comment: Wouldn't the byte representation of `value` depend on the endianness of the platform?

Comment: @Tom, yes, I added a comment later.  Provided the platforms matched it wouldn't be a problem.  x86/x64 systems are typically little-endian which is what was asked for.

Comment: OP has 8 in the last byte - isn't that big-endian?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is reasonable (although I'd use uint8_t, since you are not using the bytes as “characters”, and Peter is of course right wrt the typo), and unlike the commonly found alternatives like

```
uint32_t number = 8;
uint8_t* p = (uint8_t *) &number;
```

or

```
union {
  uint32_t number;
  uint8_t bytes[4];
} val;
val.number = 8;
// access val.bytes[0] .. val.bytes[3]
```

is even guaranteed to work. The first alternative will probably work in a debug build, but more and more compilers might break it when optimizing, while the second one tends to work in practice just about everywhere, but is explicitly marked as a bad thing™ by the language standard.

Answer (score 0):

I would drop the loop and use a "caller allocates" interface, like

```
int convert_32 (unsigned char *target, size_t size, uint32_t val)
{
if (size < 5) return -1;

target[0] = 7;
target[1] = (val >> 24) & 0xff;
target[2] = (val >> 16) & 0xff;
target[3] = (val >> 8) & 0xff;
target[4] = (val) & 0xff;

return 5;
}
```

This makes it easier for the caller to concatenate multiple fragments into one big binary packet and keep track of the used/needed buffer size.

Comment: Good point about the caller allocates.  I will use that idea I think.